# Open XML from Windows FileExplorer directly with Excel (without Popups)

Tags: excel, xml

If I add the second line to the XML-File, it causes the XML to be opened directly with MS Excel.
(By the way, these 3 lines are the only additional content to my plain XML-Data)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="XMLtoExcel.xsl"?>
```

This is very helpful for my use case, but is there a way to prevent the two annoying popups?

The "XML-Import" popup asks me

1. to open the file without a stylesheet
2. to open the file with the following XSL (I have to choose my referenced stylesheet, which is the only XSL) from a listbox. Of course this is my preferred choice.

The second "Microsoft Excel" popup shows a warning, that the content of the XML-File does not match with the file extension. It could be damaged or not safe. If I confirm the yes-button to open it nevertheless, the XML content will be loaded and displayed perfectly without any error as an Excel sheet.

Will it be possible to open the XML directly with Excel?